# How to randomly select variables from a dataset

Tags: r

Set the seed to 100, and randomly sample 500 cases from the dataset diamonds using the slice_sample() function. Save the resulting data set as my_diamonds. How do I do this?

I don't know how to process the seed in the code.

Comment: It is best to show us what you have tried thus far and where you are stuck. SO is not a code generation service. To start I will point you to the `slice_sample` [documentation](https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/reference/slice.html) specifically look at the examples. Second in R you set the seed with `set.seed`

Answer (score 0):

You just need to define `set.seed(100)` at the beginning of your code.

Code:

```
library(ggplot2)
df <- diamonds
set.seed(100)  
df1 <- slice_sample(df, n = 500)
```